# Get Username from login form and set it to a control label in another form after connected

Tags: c#, winforms

Please I'm new in C# and I'm facing this problem. I have 2 forms , one is the login form and the other is the form after login connection. I want to get the user name from the User-textbox in the login form and set it on a Label in the Second form when the user connect. Like " Welcome **User1**" and set a timer to start. Thank in advance for any suggestion. 
Below is My login code

```
namespace KPI_TRANSPORT
{
    public partial class LOGIN : Form
    {       
        public LOGIN()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void txtUsername_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar==(char)13)
                textBox2.Focus(); 
        }

        private void textBox2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
               btnLogin.PerformClick(); 
        }

        private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUsername.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("SVP Entrée votre nom d'utilisateur","Message",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                txtUsername.Focus();
                return;
            }
            try {
                KPI_DATABASEDataSet5TableAdapters.LoginTableAdapter login = new KPI_DATABASEDataSet5TableAdapters.LoginTableAdapter();
                KPI_DATABASEDataSet5.LoginDataTable dt = login.GetDataByUsernamePassword(txtUsername.Text,textBox2.Text);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                //MessageBox.Show("Connecté avec succès", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                this.Hide();
                PagePrin f1 = new PagePrin();
                LOGIN lg = new LOGIN();
                lg.Closed += (s, args) => lg.Close();
                f1.Show();

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Nom d'utilisateur ou Mot de pass incorrect", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                txtUsername.Text = "";
                textBox2.Text = "";
                txtUsername.Focus();
            }   
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { MessageBox.Show("Error"+ex); }

    }

        private void ExitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
            this.Close();
        }

        private void LOGIN_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            this.Size = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size;

            //UsernameText
            txtUsername.AutoSize = false;
            txtUsername.Height = 40;
            txtUsername.Width = 200;

            //password Text
            textBox2.AutoSize = false;
            textBox2.Height = 40;
            textBox2.Width = 200;
        }

        private void check_Text_content()
        { 
            if (txtUsername.Text !=string.Empty && textBox2.Text !=string.Empty)
            { btnLogin.Enabled=true; }
            else if (txtUsername.Text==string.Empty)
            { btnLogin.Enabled=false; }
            else if (textBox2.Text==string.Empty)
            { btnLogin.Enabled = false; }
        }      
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add public property to another form to retrieve the value you need after form is closed.

Comment: have a look at [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RToH_zbyH70). The key question here is "How to pass data from one Form to another?"

Comment: Please be careful when copy/pasting your code, no one wants to read unreadable code or off-topic functions.

Comment: Try using `Dictionary`, so you can save user data in your application tempolary

Answer (score 0):

Just pass it to another form like this:

```
public partial class LOGIN : Form
{
    public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string someString = "TestingString";
    int someInt = 123;
    SecondFrom sf = new SecondForm(someString, someInt);
    sf.Show();
}
```

Another form:

```
public partial class SecondForm : Form
{
    private string myString;
    private int myInt;

    public SecondForm(string passingString, int passingInt)
    {
        myString = passingString;
        myInt = passingInt;
    }
}
```

Like this you have passed values from `someString` and `someInt` from `LOGIN` form to `SecondForm`'s `myString` and `myInt`